# Can Google admob and Facebook audience network serve ads on the same app without using mediation?

Tags: java, android, facebook, admob, ads

Want to publish my app on play store but don't know if I can use Facebook ads and Google ads sdk together without mediation

Answer (score 0):

You can do that for now, but this option is going away https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/news-and-insights/audience-network-to-become-bidding-only-beginning-with-ios-in-2021